# bitbake network failure during npm build

Tags: node.js, yocto, bitbake, openbmc

I am trying to build openbmc image and my yocto build is failing in phosphor-webui recipe's do compile task.
Here is the do compile task

```
do_compile () {
cd ${S}
rm -rf node_modules
npm --loglevel info --proxy=${http_proxy} --https-proxy=${https_proxy} install
npm run-script build
}
```

During NPM install, network access is done to download but bitbake seem to disable the network prior to the build process. I can see this in the build log.

```
DEBUG: Attempting to disable network
DEBUG: SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH: 1636412844
```

I tried to set BB_NO_NETWORK variable to '0' but this too didnot help.

How to configure bitbake to allow network access during all tasks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you found an phosphor-webui openbmc recipe issue.

The text "Attempting to disable network" comes from [here](https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc/blob/595f63084d313c9708cb435470e6c6dcbbbbe646/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake-worker#L265) which was changed 8 days ago by [this](https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc/commit/595f63084d313c9708cb435470e6c6dcbbbbe646). So lets check upstream to see if there is a fix in review. I don't see any changes to open bmc recipes [here](https://gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz/q/project:openbmc%252Fopenbmc)

You should be able to do one of three things

1. remove phosphor-webui from you image, and build without it. Just remove phosphor-webui from you machine conf, and use webui-vue instead.
2. Roll you openbmc repo back 18 days and build before it the breaking change. `git checkout ca2f10c`
3. Fix the recipe and make everyone's life better. It looks like you need change the Datastore Variables. Something like `d.setVar(network, "true")` in the recipe file. (if that works send in a patch)

[Discord](https://discord.gg/69Km47zH98) and [eMail](https://lists.ozlabs.org/listinfo/openbmc) are the perfered ways of reaching out to the openbmc community. Let us know how it goes and if you have anymore issues.

Comment: here is the patch https://gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz/c/openbmc/openbmc/+/51227

Comment: Thanks for adding patch